# How to initialise the members of a structure when it's declared in a header file?

Tags: c, struct, initialization

I have declared a structure in header.h

```
struct SPlayer
{
    int cardValue[11];
    int score;
    int bet;
    int flag;

};
```

I want to initialise the cardValue array and make all 11 values -1 in a seperate .c file that it linked to header.h. So i tried this in a .c file. The objects player and dealer are declared in header.h

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
    {
        player->cardValue[i] = -1;
        dealer->cardValue[i] = -1;
    }
```

However, i'm getting the following error :

```
Exception thrown: write access violation.
_player was 0x1110112.
```

Please help

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Best to choose one language too. In C++ a constructor could be used but not in C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the objects player and dealer are objects of the type `struct SPlayer` then you have to write

```
for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
{
    player.cardValue[i] = -1;
    dealer.cardValue[i] = -1;
}
```

If they have the pointer type `struct SPlayer *` then you need to allocate (for example dynamically) corresponding objects of the type `struct SPlayer` to which the pointers will point to.

For example (in C )

```
struct SPlayer *player = malloc( sizeof( struct SPlayer ) );
struct SPlayer *dealer = malloc( sizeof( struct SPlayer ) );
```

Or in C++ you should use the operator new.

And after checking that the pointers are not null pointers you may use the loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
{
    player->cardValue[i] = -1;
    dealer->cardValue[i] = -1;
}
```

Pay attention to that as `John Bollinger` pointed out in a comment it is not a good idea to define objects in a header because if the header will be included in more than one module you will break the one definition rule.

Comment: Thank you. Completely forgot about malloc.

Comment: Also, the question says that `player` and `dealer` are defined in the header.  Leaving aside that that's probably poor form and definitely subject to caveats, it also tickles a difference between C and C++: in C, the initializer of a file-scope object cannot include a function call (e.g. `malloc()`), whereas in C++, it can.

Comment: @JohnBollinger He did not say that they are defined in a header. He wrote that they are declared in a header.:)

Comment: Quite right, @Vlad.  Of course, beyond the one-definition rule, the point is that if the OP addresses their problem by adding `malloc`-calling initializers to the declarations in the header, then the result is not valid C (but may still be valid C++).